# Connect external API to angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this external API on the global scope:

```
var _viewerApi = function(){
 var selectedObject = null;
 return { 
  selectObject: function(obj){
     selectedObject = obj;
  },
  getSelectedObject: function(){
    return selectedObject;
  }
 }
}

viewerApi = _viewerApi();
```

I have another external non-angular package talking with this api.

How do I attach this so angular checks the getSelectedObject? I want to fire angular events when `getSelectedObject` returns something

I guess I need to do a service and connect this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the above code in a separate file. Export that file into the relevant js file where you want to use the service. Inject that service into the angular controller you want to use within. It will create a instance of service to be used within a controller.